# Text above line in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have drawn some block elements with tikz and named them A and B.

I am trying to draw a line between them with

```
\path [line] (requested) -- (processing);
```

but I also want some text above the line.

```
\path [line] (requested) -- node [above,midway] {Some text} (processing);
```

works but if the text is very long it just keeps running without breaking the line.

How can I make sure the text wont be wider than the line itself?

## Edit

With

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto]
    \node (init) {};
    \node [block] (A) {A};
    \node [block, right=of A] (B) {B};

    \path [line] (A) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above] {My very looooooong text which is wider than the arrow below} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

How can I in a smarter way make sure there is room for the text? I have multiple boxes.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). You could give a look to `text width` key (and perhaps `align=center`), anyway.

Comment: Like @Astrinus said, setting a (max) `text width` is the solution. (By the way, Astrinus, I'd post that as an answer.)

Comment: Seen the edit. How can you have 2.5cm of text when you ask for 1cm distance between nodes? Another way could be drawing all the three nodes at the same time.

Comment: Well, you definitely need more space between the nodes, 1cm is very narrow. Can you increase it to at least 3cm?

Comment: I have so many boxes so I cannot have more spare than 1cm. Can I maybe lift the text way above the boxes?

Comment: How are the boxes laid out in your document? And how many are there? You might consider changing the layout.

Comment: Could I maybe create separate textboxes with arrows pointing at the middle of the lines? So I can annotate the lines/transitions

Answer (score 22, accepted):

two possibilities
- Specifying the distance above
- By separating the blocks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}
\usetikzlibrary[calc]

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto]
\node (init) {};
\node [block] (A) {A};
\node [block, right= of A] (B) {B};

\path [line] (A) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above=3em ] {My very looooooong text which is wider than the arrow below} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto]
\node (init) {};
\node [block] (A) {A};
\node [block, right=3cm of A] (B) {B};

\path [line] (A) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above ] {My very looooooong text which is wider than the arrow below} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

if you want center the text

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}
\usetikzlibrary[calc]

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto]
    \node (init) {};
    \node [block] (A) {A};
    \node [block, right= of A] (B) {B};

    \path [line] (A) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above=3em,align=center ] {My very looooooong text which is wider than the arrow below} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto]
    \node (init) {};
    \node [block] (A) {A};
    \node [block, right=3cm of A] (B) {B};

    \path [line] (A) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center ] {My very looooooong text which is wider than the arrow below} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: IMHO I would centre the text.

Comment: Why have you escaped all the brackets?

Comment: it is mishandled, I correct

Answer (score 3):

As exercise ...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
 start chain = going right,
block/.style = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners, 
                text width=6em, align=center, minimum height=4em,
                on chain},
every pin/.style = {inner sep=1mm, align=center, font=\footnotesize,
                    pin distance=9mm, pin edge={angle 60-, solid, black}},
                        ]
\node[block] (A) {A};
\node[block] (B) {B};

\linespread{0.9}
    \draw[-latex'] (A) to node[inner sep=0pt,
                                pin=above:My very looooooong\\
                                text which is wider\\
                                than the arrow below] {}    (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When is not enough place for text on lines this quit common way to add description of line (meaning). This text is usually smaller than main text. For it I select `\footnotesize`. I broke it manually, I think that on this way you can easily accommodate his appearances to your taste or to disposable space.

[image]

Comment: when I follow your `pin` approach for a bent arrow between A and B, `pin` arrow is also bent. How can I make `pin` arrow straight regardless of `A [->] B` arrow shape?

Comment: please, ask this as question, more people will see your problem and can help you. Even I will see MWE, by which you will show your problem.

Comment: you can find my question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361845/2288).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way it can be done with MetaPost and the `rboxes` package (complement of the `boxes` packages for round-corners boxes), for whom it may interest: putting the text label in a `\parbox` of specified width (here 2.5 cm), separating the two boxes by a shade more than this width (here 2.8 cm), and locating the label at the middle of the arrow joining both boxes. Note that I have chosen to center the text in the label, since it looks better this way.

The code has been included in a LuaLaTeX program for typesetting convenience. Also, it has allowed the use of the `em` and `en` TeX units, thanks `luamplib`'s `\mpdim` command. See also [the `gmp` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gmp) for another, not LuaLaTeX-specific but less direct way of inserting MetaPost code into a LaTeX program.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    input rboxes;
    beginfig(1);
      defaultdx := \mpdim{3em}; defaultdy := \mpdim{3ex};
      rboxit.A(btex A etex); rboxit.B(btex B etex);
      .5[A.e, B.w] = origin;
      B.w - A.e = (2.8cm, 0);
      drawboxed(A,B);
      drawarrow A.e -- B.w;
      label.top(btex \parbox{2.5cm}{\centering My very looooooong text 
        which is wider than the arrow below} etex, .5[A.e,B.w]);
    endfig;
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]